# glewInit function throws error code 0x0000007F (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

First, I created an old OpenGL context to load OpenGL extensions. After that, I tried to create a new OpenGL context, but function 'wglCreateContextAttribsARB' threw error code 0xC007000D. So I locked where the error was and I saw glewInit is the function which throws the error code 0x0000007F, but glewInit returns GLEW_OK, which means that there was any error in glewInit...

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR *PixelFormat = new PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR[1];
    HWND *hFakeWnd = new HWND[1];
    int ChoosenPixelFormat = 0;
    UINT NumFormats = 0;

    *hFakeWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, cWindow.lpszClassName, L"Fake", 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    ZeroMemory(PixelFormat, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
    PixelFormat->nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    PixelFormat->nVersion = 1;
    PixelFormat->iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    PixelFormat->dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    PixelFormat->cColorBits = 32;
    PixelFormat->cDepthBits = 24;
    PixelFormat->cStencilBits = 8;
    PixelFormat->iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    hDC = GetDC(*hFakeWnd);

    if(hDC == NULL) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error getting a device context from a window!");
        return false;
    }

    ChoosenPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat);

    if(!ChoosenPixelFormat) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error choosing a valid pixel format (old)!");
        return false;
    }

    if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC, ChoosenPixelFormat, PixelFormat)) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error setting a pixel format (old)!");
        return false;
    }

    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);

    if(!hRC) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error creating an old OpenGL context!");
        return false;
    }

    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

    //MessageBoxA(hWnd, (char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION), "Version", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    glewExperimental = true;

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error linking OpenGL functions!");
        return false;
    }

    destroyOpenGLContext(*hFakeWnd, hDC, hRC);

    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

    if(hDC == NULL) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error getting a device context from a window!");
        return false;
    }

    const int *AttribList = new int[] {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        0
    };

    if(!wglChoosePixelFormatARB(hDC, AttribList, NULL, 1, &ChoosenPixelFormat, &NumFormats)) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error choosing a valid pixel format (new)!");
        return false;
    }

    const int *ContextAttribList = new int[] {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4, 
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 5, 
        0
    };

    hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC, NULL, ContextAttribList);

    char error[9];
    int nError = GetLastError();
    _itoa_s(nError, error, (size_t)9, 16);
    PostErrorMessage(hWnd, error);

    if(!hRC) {
        PostErrorMessage(hWnd, "Error creating an OpenGL context (new)!");
        return false;
    }

    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

    delete[] AttribList;
    delete[] ContextAttribList;
    delete[] PixelFormat;
    delete[] hFakeWnd;

    return true;
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Do you have a specific question you would like answered? What debugging steps have you gone through? What trouble have you run into?

Comment: At first, I compiled this code (it's not fully posted). When I tried to open the exe, message box "Error creating an OpenGL context (new)!" appears. So I wrote a piece of code which tells me the error code after calling the function 'wglCreateContextAttribsARB', and it gave me the error code '0xC007000D'. To be sure that this function is the problen, I checked all functions using this piece of code that gives me the error code. Before glewInit, it doesn't give me any error, but after glewInit call, it gives me the error code '0x0000007F'

Comment: I rewrote the entire code and it gives me the same error. 

I called the funcion glGetString(GL_VERSION) and it gives me 4.5.0 NVIDIA 353.06